# How can you centre an image within the image control in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have got an image in an image control on a report in SSRS 2008. The image is coming from an external source, and varies in width. I would like to centre the image within the control, but the image control does not have an equivalent of the text box's TextAlign property to allow right/left/center alignment to be done automatically.

I have seen methods to dynamically calculate the amount of left padding as a hack to solve this, http://blogs.msdn.com/chrishays/archive/2004/10/27/CenteredImages.aspx, but the solution gives an error in SSRS 2008, perhaps not surprising given the age of the article.

Has anybody got a solution to this for SSRS 2008?

Answer (score 0):

Select textbox, go to properties of textbox. Find Background Image property, change BackgrounRepeat value to Clip.

Answer (score -2):

Why can't you just set sizing to "fit proportional" ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, "Fit proportional" just affects the scaling of the image, it does not affect how it is aligned within the control.

Comment: Wouldn't you want the image placeholder to be a fixed size? Regardless, this may be of interest as an alternative solution http://bobp1339.blogspot.com/2007/11/dynamic-images-in-reports-slight-return.html